# How to call const std::function<>& parameter in mock expectation?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googlemock

I have mocked function like:

```
virtual void MyClass::foo(const std::function<void()>& callback);
```

I want to set expectation for `foo`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(MyClassMock, foo(testing::_));
```

and then I want to call received callback when expectation is fulfilled.

How to do that using gmock?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option #1

```
EXPECT_CALL(MyClassMock, foo(testing::_))
    .Times(1) 
    .WillOnce(testing::InvokeArgument<0>());
```

#### Option #2

```
EXPECT_CALL(MyClassMock, foo(testing::_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(testing::Invoke([](std::function<void()> f){f();}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but the principle should get you there.

Change your `EXPECT_CALL` to repeatedly invoke a function. This function should be global/static, probably located in the same file as your expectations. `Invoke` automatically forwards the arguments so the parameter list should match.

```
EXPECT_CALL(MyClassMock, foo(testing::_))
    .WillRepeatedly(Invoke(myCallbackFunc));

...

static void myCallbackFunc(const std::function<void()>& callback)
{
    callback();
}
```

More ways of invoking functions after an `EXPECT` can be seen on the [GoogleMock Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#using-a-function-or-a-functor-as-an-action).